# How to solve this nontrivial induction problem?

Tags: integration, induction

$$\log2 = \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} + (-1)^k2\int_{0}^1\frac{t^{2k+1}}{1+t^2}dt$$

I'm having trouble even getting the base case.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the point is to prove that formula for $\ln 2$ - it's easy to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{0}^1 \frac{t^{2k+1}}{1+t^2}dt = 0$

Comment: @Thomas: Good point, I removed my comment because using it would result in circularity and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The base case is trivial if you start at $k=0$. If you insist on starting at $k=1$, divide out the integrand: $$\int_0^1\frac{t^3~dt}{1+t^2}=\int_0^1\left(t-\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)dt\;;$$ then the integration and evaluation are easy. And this suggests how to handle the induction step:

$$\frac{t^{2k+3}}{1+t^2}=\frac{(1+t^2)t^{2k+1}-t^{2k+1}}{1+t^2}=t^{2k+1}-\frac{t^{2k+1}}{1+t^2}\;.$$

Comment: One more reason to start counting at zero...

Comment: @Asaf: :-) Though to be fair, the $k=1$ case really was what suggested the induction step to me.

Comment: Well if you start at $k =0$, is the sum defined?

Comment: @Hal: Yes: it’s $0$.

Comment: @Hal Yes, an empty sum is alwasys zero.

Answer (score 0):

For the base case, the sum is 1. To evaluate the integral, notice that $\frac{t^3}{t^2+1}=t-\frac{t}{t^2+1}$. Then the integral evaluates very easily to $(1-\log2)$, so we have $\log2=1-(1-\log2)=\log2$.

For the inductive step, simply show that $\frac{1}{k}=2\int_{0}^1\frac{t^{2k+3}-t^{2k+1}}{1+t^2}dt$. If I am not mistaken, you can evaluate the integral fairly easily.

Comment: You can actually start at the case $k=0$, although that might be confusing for someone note used to empty sums.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right.